# MySQL server not accepting remote connections

Tags: c++, mysql, database

I'm using the C++ connector and one of the example code that goes along with it and it wont allow external connections to connect to my database when i change the host address from localhost to my computer's address where the server is running.

This connects perfectly without any problems:

```
con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "Shawn", "my_pass");
```

But obviously this wont work when i change computers, so i set the host address to my computer where the server is running like this:

```
con = driver->connect("tcp://108.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306", "Shawn", "my_pass");
```

**x's stand for numbers to hide my IP*

**Why won't it connect?**

I allowed Norton 360(takes over windows firewall) to accept any and all connections and ports from my program.

I gave the user "Shawn" the privledges necessary to accept all hosts via "%":

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYu8z.png

I get this mysql error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/98nDI.png

Comment: did you read http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html ?

Comment: I have read articles just like that wanting me to change the "bind-address" in a my.cnf file, but all the my.cnf files on my computer relating to mysql DO NOT have the "bind-address" statement in any of the files. I have no idea where people are finding this special my.cnf file

Comment: if you are not finding it, you just may add it.

Comment: in fact you need to enable the networking "module" and allow access for the user from your client address (or "%" if you want to - what you correctly already did).

Comment: how do i enable the networking "module"? googleing gives me nothing

Comment: if you find `skip-networking` - putt a `#`infront of it - like http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html sais.

Comment: I cant find skip-networking either in any my.cnf files on my computer :S

Comment: MySQL answers my exact error here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html But they just say to not bind-address=127.0.0.1 which i dont know how to access

Comment: I found the my.ini file, but it doesn't matter because mysql workbench told me this upon starting the server " Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306" Since its binded to all IP address this cant be the problem its not connecting :/ back to phase 1

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass Socket parameter with this connection string.
or
you can try with the hostname instead of ipaddress.

if still youre issue is not resolved .Firewalls/iptables are enabled at server side so u need to stop it.

Comment: What do you mean hostname? whats an example of a hostname so i know what you're talking about, please